# Any way to use strings as the scores in a Redis sorted set (zset)?

Tags: redis, dataset, sorting

Or maybe the question should be: What's the best way to represent a string as a number, such that sorting their numeric representations would give the same result as if sorted as strings?  I devised a way that could sort up to 9 characters per string, but it seems like there should be a much better way.

In advance, I don't think using Redis's lexicographical commands will work.  (See the following example.)

Example: Suppose I want to presort all of the names linked to some ID so that I can use ZINTERSTORE to quickly get an ordered list of IDs based on their names (without using redis' SORT command).  Ideally I would have the IDs as the zset's members, and the numeric representation of each name would be the zset's scores.

Does that make sense?  Or am I going about it wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to implement? What's your use case?

Comment: We use [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) for those kind of use cases all the time.
Example (Lua):
  `cData = redis.call(
    'zrangebylex',
    cSliceKey,
    '[' .. cSliceFilter,
    '(' .. cSliceFilter .. '\001') `
In this example, we use chr(0) as a delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use an order preserving hash function to generate a score for each id. While it appears you've written one, you've already found out that the score's range allows you to use only the first 9 characters (it would be interesting to see your function btw).

Instead of this approach, here's a simpler one that would be easier IMO -  use set members of the form `<name>:<id>` and set the score to 0. You'll be able to use lexicographical ordering this way and use something like `split(':')` to get the id from the set's members.

Comment: Brilliant!  I hadn't considered adding the ID at the end.  Although I will probably set the scores to 1 so I can use some of the weighted functions.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Well, I just sat down and started working on the project that this question was about, and immediately realized this won't work for what I want to do, or at least not as efficiently as I would like.  I would like to be able to use ZINTERSTORE to intersect a SET of IDs with the ZSET, and this would require the ZSET to use the IDs as its members.

Comment: x-post from the mailing list - discussion continued there: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/ifmotqIDwi8/2A6yG4pgYJsJ